# Does an isogeny between tori induce an isomorphism of the Lie algebras of their lft Néron models?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-groups, neron-models

Let $f:T_1 \to T_2$ be an isogeny of tori over a number field $K$. Does $f$ induce an isomorphism of the Lie algebras of the lft Néron models of $T_1$ and $T_2$ ? Are there some interesting properties of the induced morphism between the Néron models that we can exhibit ? I am mostly interested in the following set of hypotheses:

- $T_1$ and $T_2$ are split by a tamely ramified extension of $K$
- The same as above, and furthermore $T_1$ is a product of Weil restrictions of $\mathbb{G}_m$ along finite tamely ramified extensions

Comment: What do you mean by the Lie algebra the Néron model? For me it is a R-module, and an isogeny of Néron models induce surjective map with finite cokernel, not an isomorphism.

Comment: You are right, I was thinking about affine algebraic groups over a field and I generalized too much. I will edit that out.